# Where is the "2017 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire?"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, election

Not sure if Grace Note has to actually post it or if its completely automated. I would've guessed automated. But generally when the Election goes up to take Nominations there's also a "2017 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire" which doesn't seem to be here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is, "Whoops Memorial Day happened and Grace Note (amongst the rest of a lot of the company located in the US) was off on that Monday, and didn't remember until this morning."

The long answer is... actually identical to the short answer, just with all this extra wording about a short answer and a long answer.

It is up now [here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5446/2017-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).